# Add css style to all elements with specific class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some lists in my page which are the same

```
<ul class="tabItem">
    <li class="active">
        <hr>
        <a href="#tab-1">tab1</a>
        <hr>
    </li>
    <li>
        <hr>
        <a href="#tab-2">tab2</a>
        <hr>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

How can I add `css` to all `<ul>`tags with `.tabItem` class at the whole page using jQuery?

Currently I'm doing this, which works only on the first `<li>` childs

```
$(".tabItem li").children('hr').eq(0).css({"transform": "translateY(-12px)"});
$(".tabItem li").children('hr').eq(1).css({"transform": "translateY(12px)"});
```

Comment: why not just use CSS? do you need to use jquery?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to get the first two `<li>` in `.tabItem`?

Comment: @JacobGray Yes! I'm using this in `.tabItem li:hover` to add effects. And I need this to add to all `hr`s in the all `<li>` tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's all ul tags with .tabItem class:

```
$('ul.tabItem').css({ });
```

Here's the child action you're attempting:

```
$('ul.tabItem li hr:first-child').css({"transform": "translateY(-12px)"});
$('ul.tabItem li hr:last-child').css({"transform": "translateY(12px)"});
```

Although just using CSS would be better:

```
ul.tabItem li hr:first-child {
    transform: translate(-12px);
}
ul.tabItem li hr:last-child {
    transform: translate(12px);
}
```

Using CSS method then there's no JavaScript necessary.

Comment: I need the jQuery cause i'm using this for adding effect in mouse move. So I used your jQuery code and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: could you use the ":hover" CSS selector to add the affect on mouse hover over the LI tag?

Comment: Yes. But then I need to remove the transform after mouse leaving

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.tabItem').css({"transform": "translateY(-12px)"});
```

or for `hr` tag

```
$('ul.tabItem hr').css({"transform": "translateY(-12px)"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.tabItem").addClass("yourClass");
```

With this, you can add a class to all of the elements that have the class tabItem already. In your class you can add all the styles that you need to provide, which is usually a better practice than just assigning it to the element itself.

If you still want to assign the styles directly, take a look at the `css` method in jQuery.

Comment: I understand this... however the answer does not seem too bad regarding the question itself _How can I add css to all <ul>tags with .tabItem class at the whole page using jQuery?_

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with just css no need to use jquery

like so:

```
<style>
.tabItem hr {
    transform: translateY(-12px)
}
</style>
```